# Display css grid-items in Row order not Column order

Tags: css, grid-layout, css-grid

Typical CSS grid-layout places items in the grid left to right, then wraps to the next row, similar to using `float:left` on a series of block elements.

I want to display (N) items vertically then start a new column. Is this possible?

Currently, I do this with JavaScript, inserting `</div><div>` tags after every Nth item but was hoping for a CSS solution.

**For example:** Given an alphabetical list of 24 items that I want to display in 3 columns. 8 rows x 3 columns.

Items 1-8 will display in column 1, 9-16 will display in column 2 and finally, 17-24 will display in column 3.

```
 1 | 9  | 17

 2 | 10 | 18

 3 | 11 | 19

and so on...

 8 | 16 | 24
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

```css
.outer-1 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
    height: 300px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box-1 {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.box-2 {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: orange;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-1">
  <div class="box-1">1</div>
  <div class="box-2">2</div>
  <div class="box-1">3</div>
  <div class="box-2">4</div>
  <div class="box-1">5</div>
  <div class="box-2">6</div>
  <div class="box-1">7</div>
  <div class="box-2">8</div>
  <div class="box-1">9</div>
  <div class="box-2">10</div>
  <div class="box-1">11</div>
  <div class="box-2">12</div>
  <div class="box-1">13</div>
  <div class="box-2">14</div>
  <div class="box-1">15</div>
  <div class="box-2">16</div>
  <div class="box-1">17</div>
  <div class="box-2">18</div>
  <div class="box-1">19</div>
  <div class="box-2">20</div>
  <div class="box-1">21</div>
  <div class="box-2">22</div>
  <div class="box-1">23</div>
  <div class="box-2">24</div>
  <div class="box-1">25</div>
  <div class="box-2">26</div>
  <div class="box-1">27</div>
  <div class="box-2">28</div>
  <div class="box-1">29</div>
  <div class="box-2">30</div>
  <div class="box-1">31</div>
  <div class="box-2">32</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to support IE 9 and below, you can use [column-count](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-count).

```css
ul {
  column-count: 3;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
  <li>D</li>
  <li>E</li>
  <li>F</li>
  <li>G</li>
  <li>H</li>
  <li>I</li>
  <li>J</li>
  <li>K</li>
  <li>L</li>
  <li>M</li>
  <li>N</li>
  <li>O</li>
  <li>P</li>
  <li>Q</li>
  <li>R</li>
  <li>S</li>
  <li>T</li>
  <li>U</li>
  <li>V</li>
  <li>W</li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>Y</li>
  <li>Z</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `grid-auto-flow: column` ?

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  /* max 8 rows down before spilling to next column. */
  grid-template-rows: 30px 30px 30px 30px 30px 30px 30px 30px;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}
```

Fill your `.container` with block elements... it should flow in as rows down, adding columns as necessary.

Comment: browser conflict, mate !

Comment: ah right ... people still use IE.  Bummer.

Comment: Its just rediculous bro. Most of them want to support IE but u know in fact no one want to touch dirty IE in practise. Some company only list IE support for hiring dev to make sure they understand things, but in reality IE is completely out of the way 

@Sean

Comment: @CuongHoang Well you know what they say - during any web development, 10% of your time is spent writing beautiful code.  The other 90% is spent destroying it so it will work with IE.